# Prevent Chrome from closing tab that downloads CSV

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I want to find out the URL to a specific CSV file on a web page. The page is built using some arcane system called QLIK, and for some reason, the CSV path does not show up in my networks panels in Chrome when hitting the download button.

When I download the CSV, a new tab is opened. I want to keep that tab open and inspect the developer tools. But Chrome immediately closes it. How do I prevent Chrome from closing the tab?

Comment: [Chrome Dev Tools: How to trace network for a link that opens a new tab?](//stackoverflow.com/q/16210468)

Comment: As it is, the DevTools are doing what they are supposed to as expected. What you want isn't achievable. If you provide us with the case you're hitting and what you are testing for perhaps an alternative method can be found.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Chrome doesn't pipe network information on *downloads* to the network panel. They go through a different pathway then page-pound network operations. You can't inspect binary downloads.